Ubuntu 24.04 - Dark mode but some parts of UI is not dark
I've changed my UI setting to be dark mode, but some part of the UI is not dark. What happen here? Is it a known issue? See screenshot for issue.


Does this answer your question? Right click menu and calendar are still white even after enabling the dark mode The issue probably exists in 24.04 and the fix the same

@graham yes it did! Thanks!
